# How to sharing my NFC tag(on my phone) to another phone through network like https?

Tags: android, nfc

I don't know much about nfc and the nfc tags, I just wondering can I send the nfc tag's data to another phone through network, then that phone can read that data and create a copy of it on its own,finally it could open the door that protected by the keycard.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKyfx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading NFC data (payload) isn't a problem, sending this in any way also, the real question is that receiving data-copy Android device can act as and emulate same NFC type. check out [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138077/can-an-android-nfc-phone-act-as-an-nfc-tag) for more options, but in short: that may depend on source tag type

your scenario looks very similar to card data stealing, NFC-based security systems are oftenly using some prevention, e.g. are reading some hard-coded and whitelisted card [uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080131/nfc-tags-unique-id), which [can't be emulated easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484272/emulate-nfc-card-with-selected-uid-on-android)

Comment: Note just using a UID is basically having no security at all with NFC as the UID was not designed to be secure, it is easily faked with the right hardware, really you need to cryptographically secure some data on the card but it's still possible to do man in the middle attacks. For Android you just need to build your own custom rom.